# Using xargs instead of GNU Parallel

Tags: xargs

GNU Parallel can generate all combinations of input, copy shell functions and run them on 3 remote servers without mixing the output, retrying the command if it fails:

```
#!/bin/bash

env_parallel --session
process_output() {
  perl -ne '$/=undef; $|=1; @a=split//;
      while(@a){
        print ".",shift @a;
        select($a,$a,$a,0.100);
      }';
}
env_parallel --retries 4 -Sserver{1..3},: \
  'echo X={1} Y={2} Z={3} | process_output' \
  ::: "a'  \"b"{1..3} ::: "c\"  'd"{3..4} ::: "e\$  f'"{7..8}
```

Output:

```
.X.=.a.'. . .".b.1. .Y.=.c.". . .'.d.3. .Z.=.e.$. . .f.'.7.
.X.=.a.'. . .".b.1. .Y.=.c.". . .'.d.3. .Z.=.e.$. . .f.'.8.
.X.=.a.'. . .".b.1. .Y.=.c.". . .'.d.4. .Z.=.e.$. . .f.'.7.
.X.=.a.'. . .".b.1. .Y.=.c.". . .'.d.4. .Z.=.e.$. . .f.'.8.
.X.=.a.'. . .".b.2. .Y.=.c.". . .'.d.3. .Z.=.e.$. . .f.'.7.
.X.=.a.'. . .".b.2. .Y.=.c.". . .'.d.3. .Z.=.e.$. . .f.'.8.
.X.=.a.'. . .".b.2. .Y.=.c.". . .'.d.4. .Z.=.e.$. . .f.'.7.
.X.=.a.'. . .".b.2. .Y.=.c.". . .'.d.4. .Z.=.e.$. . .f.'.8.
.X.=.a.'. . .".b.3. .Y.=.c.". . .'.d.3. .Z.=.e.$. . .f.'.7.
.X.=.a.'. . .".b.3. .Y.=.c.". . .'.d.3. .Z.=.e.$. . .f.'.8.
.X.=.a.'. . .".b.3. .Y.=.c.". . .'.d.4. .Z.=.e.$. . .f.'.7.
.X.=.a.'. . .".b.3. .Y.=.c.". . .'.d.4. .Z.=.e.$. . .f.'.8.
```

`xargs -P$(nproc)` can run one job per processor.

Given

- the function 
  `process_output`,
- the servers to run on (server1, server2, server3),
- the argument groups (`a'  "b1, a'  "b2, a'  "b3`;`c"  'd1, c"  'd2, c"  'd3`;`e$  f'7, e$  f'8`)

how can you emulate GNU Parallel using `xargs` to get the same done using `process_output` and the servers?

Comment: you mean to just produce the same output with `xargs -P<N>` OR it should also fulfill all conditions like distributing `process_output` calls on 3 remote servers?

Comment: Based on my experience: there is no easy way to emulate "parallel" with "xargs". It is allways easier to find package of GNU Parallel on your OS and Platfrom than create something new and update and support this solution after. By the way, what are your restrictions to use xargs instead of parallel ?

Comment: I think what you're really asking is how to run parallel to execute all work on one machine/container. To do this, you simply drop the reference to your remote servers.

Comment: @ole are you debugging gnu parallell? ;-), or just asking whether xargs *actually* can do the same job?